# A complex matrix commuting with all diagonalizable matrices is a scalar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

This question is from an old comprehensive exam

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix, which commutes with all diagonalizable $n\times n$ complex matrices. Prove that $A$ is a constant times the identity matrix. Hint: What matrices commute with all diagonal matrices?

The hint says to find the matrices that commute with all diagonal matrices, which should themselves be diagonal.

**What I've tried**: Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, $B$ be a diagonalizable $n\times n$ complex matrix  such that $P^{-1}BP = D$, a diagonal matrix.

As $AB =BA$ then $P^{-1}ABP =P^{-1}BAP$, so
$$P^{-1}APP^{-1}BP =P^{-1}BPP^{-1}AP$$
Which means that
$$(P^{-1}AP)D = D(P^{-1}AP)$$
And so $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal, so $A$ is diagonalizable, and moreover is simultaneously diagonalizable.

But from here I'm stuck. I know that $A$ commutes with all diagonalizable matrices, so this should always work, but I don't see how to get that $A$ is a scalar matrix.

Am I missing something obvious? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you can show that only a diagonal matrix commutes with all diagonal matrices (this is a triviality, by comparing matrix coefficients). Now notice that matrix that commutes with all matrices must be diagonal *with respect to all bases* (conjugate and repeat the previous argument). This means that every vector is an eigenvector, which, in turn, obviously means that the matrix is a multiple of the identity.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of grinding through:

let $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag} \{1,...,n \}$ and compute
$[\Lambda A - A \Lambda]_{ij}$ to show that $A$ is diagonal.

Pick $i \neq j$ and let $V=e_i e_j^T + e_j e_i^T$. Note that $V$ is symmetric hence diagonalisable and compute
$VA-AV$ to show that $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$.

Answer (score 1):

So, the hint points out that if $A $ commutes with every diagonalizable matrix,  then it commutes with every *diagonal* matrix.

Look at the $2×2$ case.  We get $A $ commuting with $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix} $.  But that means if $A=\begin  {pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end {pmatrix} $, we get $\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\c&0\end {pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix} $.  So we know $A $ is diagonal. (In the general case, use the matrix with a  $1$ on the $jj $-th entry and $0$'s everywhere else to show that the  $j $-th row and $j$- th column are zero off the diagonal.)

Next, I claim $a=d $.  Because we know $\begin  {pmatrix}0&a\\d&0\end {pmatrix}=A\begin {pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end {pmatrix}=\begin  {pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end {pmatrix}A=\begin  {pmatrix}0&d\\a&0\end {pmatrix}$.

Now you *just* need to generalize to the  $n×n $ case.